# Pycharm compilation error

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I am seeing following error while compiling python program in pycharm . It is a community download and I am beginner to this.

```
    C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/udaya/PycharmProjects/yout3.4/abc.py
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 62, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 400, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "C:\Python27\lib\UserDict.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_abcoll.py", line 11, in <module>
    from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
ImportError: cannot import name ABCMeta

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any one can please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have named your file `abc.py` , that is shadowing the library module `abc` causing the error. This can be seen in the path you give to run the program -

> C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/udaya/PycharmProjects/yout3.4/**abc.py**

Rename your file to something else, so that it does not shadow any libraries.